# Replacing multiprocessing with dask equivalent

Tags: python, cluster-computing

There is a script which performs a tedious function with the help of multiprocessing. This script involves lots of log file processing and it takes lots of time when it involves hundreds or several thousands of them.

I am new to cluster computing, this is why I would like to know if there is a way to replace the multiprocessing workers, that are probably running on one machine power, with Dask workers that will spread over several machines? By the way, for what I know the cluster manager in the background is SGE.

If it is possible than, how can this be done?

Do I need to coordinate it with the IT?

Comment: It sounds as if, in the end, you'll be limited by the (disk) I/O throughput; depending a bit of course on the processing time, but log files in general don't involve heavy computations when processing. But, even several processing several thousands of files is generally fast enough, so I'm guessing there's more to it than what you mention: does processing a single file takes lots of time (and if so, how much? one minute, one hour)?

Comment: This is not really a Python question; distributed computing can be done with any language. And I find the Python-2.7 tag a bit omnious: is this one of those clusters that's stuck in the past, still running e.g. CentOS 7? Perhaps IT has made more recent versions of Python available as well on the cluster? That might overall be better.

Comment: All in all, yes, I would contact IT first, since they'll be more familiar with things, and, depending on your organisation, it'll be easier to have an interactive brainstorm about your problem. Or find a knowledgable colleague; that's often the best place to start with.

Comment: Processing a single file takes around a minute. By the way, IT suggested using gnu_parallel in order to run the script over several servers in the cluster. The reason I tagged it with Python 2.7 is because the script is old and I would like to leave it as is. I believe that the solution will be limited to Python 2.7 if I will integrate it in the code. Unless I will wrap the code with another script